# Trying to create a div with resizable dragger

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm pretty sure there is already an example for this but I couldn't find one, and I don't know exactly what to search for.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTkjB.jpg

I am trying to make a resizable div from the button circled in red above.

The photo behind this div comes from a slick slider ( http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ ).

```
<div class="slider-for">
                <img src="images/product0.jpg" alt="">
                <img src="images/product1.jpg" alt="">
                <img src="images/product2.jpg" alt="">
                <img src="images/product3.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
```

I was thinking of making a width 0 div above, and then with the slider, increase its width with js maybe.

In this div, I want to put a recipe for that certain product. I have 4 photos, so the content has to change depending on picture. ( so it's not static content).

Does this need to be made in php?

Comment: No, this is a task for client-side scripting. I'd suggest you read about angular.js (https://angularjs.org/) or react.js (https://facebook.github.io/react/).

Comment: Search Internet for "js image compare slider", there are plenty of JS libraries available. This one: https://juxtapose.knightlab.com/ seems to work nicely.

Comment: No. It ca be made with simple JS and CSS. Their is not even need to learn angular or react for it. I will put up a jsfiddle in few minutes

Comment: @AndrewSklyarevsky i already found that out, but i only have 1 image. I tried twenty twenty ( 1 image, 1 text) didn't work ou that well.

Comment: @HarshalCarpenter looking forward to that jsfiddle :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would be helpful to you:

https://jsfiddle.net/u0Ljnttg/1/

Its little bit complicated, but still good enough. :)

Just for sake of SO:
JS:

```
var links = document.getElementById("imageLinks");
links.onmousedown = function(e) {
  var theSrc = e.target.dataset.src;
  if (theSrc) {
    str = "url(\"" + theSrc + "\");";
    //Sorry for using this:
    document.getElementById("imageBack").setAttribute("style", "background-image:" + str)
  }
}


var resizer = document.getElementById("content-resize");
resizer.onmousedown = resizableStart;

function resizableStart(e) {
  var elem = document.getElementById("content");
  elem.originalW = elem.clientWidth;
  this.onmousemove = resizableCheck;
  this.onmouseup = this.onmouseout = resizableEnd;
}

function resizableCheck(e) {
  var elem = document.getElementById("content");
  if (elem.clientWidth === elem.originalW) {
    elem.originalX = e.clientX;
    this.onmousemove = resizableMove;
  }
}

function resizableMove(e) {
  var elem = document.getElementById("content");
  var newW = elem.originalW - e.clientX + elem.originalX;
  if (newW < elem.originalW) {
    elem.style.width = newW + 'px';
  }
}

function resizableEnd() {
  this.onmousemove = this.onmouseout = this.onmouseup = null;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='images' id="imageBack" style="background-image: url('http://data.whicdn.com/images/20948152/large.png')">

    <div class='content' id="content">
      <div id="imageLinks">
        <a href="#" data-src='http://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/660/cpsprodpb/1325A/production/_88762487_junk_food.jpg'>1</a>
        <a href="#" data-src='http://i.imgur.com/NhDejjN.jpg'>2</a>
        <a href="#" data-src='https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/80/40/9d/80409d8c06d21e0c0416a40c2176def3.jpg'>3</a>
        <a href="#" data-src='http://data.whicdn.com/images/20948152/large.png'>4</a>
      </div>
      <span id="content-resize"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html,
body {
  min-height: 100% !important;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.images {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100% !important;
  height: 100%;
}

#content {
  min-height: 100% !important;
  height: 100%;
  /*Change this to change width*/
  width: 70%;
  resize: horizontal;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  background: white;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

span {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 20px);
  left: -10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for taking the time to write this. 

For me the slider seems to be buggy for some reason. can only drag/resize 1 time then it will only select the right text ( 1234)

Comment: @VladMarinescu yeah i see that now :( .. dont know why its like this .. if i am able to solve. I will update it here. Thanks!

Comment: @VladMarinescu I asked a question on why it was not smooth, here refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39476872/i-made-a-pure-js-resizeable-element-but-the-resizing-element-is-not-smooth-how/39481016#39481016 .Hope it helps you! :)

Comment: Yep. This is perfect. All I have have to do is set the slider position to maximum right, but I can work that out :D Thank you for taking the time to fix this

Comment: @VladMarinescu This was fun! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you already solved this issue, but since you helped me on the other question, I am interested in helping you with this.

You have some options.

1. Use pure JavaScript. You can use a lib (eg: [this](https://interactjs.io/)) for that.
2. Use Jquery $().draggable() propriety. [This might help for styling the button.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40232949/styling-close-and-resize-button-for-content-editable-div-in-css-and-adding-rsize).
3. Using pure HTML & CSS `resize`. This is not good, since you cannot apply any style to the `<div>`.
4. You can make a workaround mixing three `<div>` elements,

   - One of them with `position: fixed`. This is your background.
   - Another for the container (with a width set manually to hide the page from user). Remove the scrollbar and force the width of your `html, body` to match your screen.
   - Another `<div>` inside the container for your content. This should be able to move horizontally to show and hide the elements.