# I made a pure JS resizeable element, but the resizing element is not smooth. How do I make this more smooth?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I made this thing where half of the element is resizable and which exposes the parent element and you can see the `background-image` of the parent element. Everything else seems to work fine except that the resizing is not smooth enough. After first time resizing, it just starts to stick and not perform well.

Link: https://jsfiddle.net/mcquintrix/u0Ljnttg/2/

```js
var links = document.getElementById("imageLinks");
links.onmousedown = function(e) {
  var theSrc = e.target.dataset.src;
  if (theSrc) {
    str = "url(\"" + theSrc + "\");";
    //Sorry for using this:
    document.getElementById("imageBack").setAttribute("style", "background-image:" + str)
  }
}

var resizer = document.getElementById("content-resize");
resizer.onmousedown = resizableStart;

function resizableStart(e) {
  var elem = document.getElementById("content");
  elem.originalW = elem.clientWidth;
  this.onmousemove = resizableCheck;
  this.onmouseup = this.onmouseout = resizableEnd;
}

function resizableCheck(e) {
  var elem = document.getElementById("content");
  if (elem.clientWidth === elem.originalW) {
    elem.originalX = e.clientX;
    this.onmousemove = resizableMove;
  }
}

function resizableMove(e) {
  var elem = document.getElementById("content");
  var newW = elem.originalW - e.clientX + elem.originalX;
  if (newW < elem.originalW) {
    elem.style.width = newW + 'px';
  }
}

function resizableEnd() {
  this.onmousemove = this.onmouseout = this.onmouseup = null;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  min-height: 100% !important;
  height: 100%;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.images {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100% !important;
  height: 100%;
}
#content {
  min-height: 100% !important;
  height: 100%;
  /*Change this to change width*/
  width: 70%;
  resize: horizontal;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  background: white;
}
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
span {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 20px);
  left: -10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='images' id="imageBack" style="background-image: url('http://data.whicdn.com/images/20948152/large.png')">
    <div class='content' id="content">
      <div id="imageLinks">
        <a href="#" data-src='http://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/660/cpsprodpb/1325A/production/_88762487_junk_food.jpg'>1</a>
        <a href="#" data-src='http://i.imgur.com/NhDejjN.jpg'>2</a>
        <a href="#" data-src='https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/80/40/9d/80409d8c06d21e0c0416a40c2176def3.jpg'>3</a>
        <a href="#" data-src='http://data.whicdn.com/images/20948152/large.png'>4</a>
      </div>
      <span id="content-resize"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Code required to understand the question must be pasted directly into the question, not only available via an external link.

Comment: @jfriend00 done

Comment: The reason why its not very responsive and seems to stop a lot is because you are attaching the listener to mouseMove over the button.  The mouse can quickly run outside the button and it will stop firing.  A better strategy is to set a down flag and watch the mouseMove within the parent.

Comment: Your   if (newW < elem.originalW) is what keeps it from being able to be downsized after you pull out the width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Harshal Carpenter, here's my snippet:

What I've done to your code is that:

1.Remove these lines, which prevents the image to become smaller after the resize it to larger previously.

```
if (newW < elem.originalW) {
   elem.style.width = newW + 'px';
}
```

2. Remove the `this.onmouseout` to prevent resizing stop when you leave your mouse from that circular handle. You might want to continue resizing because your mouse might move to fast before the circular knob do, which end up your mouse cursor exiting the circular knob.
3. attach the mouse event listener to the `div#imageBack` instead of the `div#content-resize`, the same reason as above, you might want it to continue dragging even if the mouse leaves the `div#content-resize`.

```js
var links = document.getElementById("imageLinks");
links.onmousedown = function(e) {
  var theSrc = e.target.dataset.src;
  if (theSrc) {
    str = "url(\"" + theSrc + "\");";
    //Sorry for using this:
    document.getElementById("imageBack").setAttribute("style", "background-image:" + str)
  }
}


var container = document.getElementById("imageBack");
var resizer = document.getElementById("content-resize");
container.onmousedown = resizableStart;

function resizableStart(e) {
 if(e.target == resizer){
   var elem = document.getElementById("content");
    elem.originalW = elem.clientWidth;
    this.onmousemove = resizableCheck;
    this.onmouseup = resizableEnd;
  }
}

function resizableCheck(e) {
  var elem = document.getElementById("content");
  if (elem.clientWidth === elem.originalW) {
    elem.originalX = e.clientX;
    this.onmousemove = resizableMove;
  }
}

function resizableMove(e) {
  var elem = document.getElementById("content");
  var newW = elem.originalW - e.clientX + elem.originalX;
  elem.style.width = newW + 'px';
}

function resizableEnd() {
  this.onmousemove = this.onmouseout = this.onmouseup = null;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  min-height: 100% !important;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.images {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100% !important;
  height: 100%;
}

#content {
  min-height: 100% !important;
  height: 100%;
  /*Change this to change width*/
  width: 70%;
  resize: horizontal;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  background: white;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

span {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 20px);
  left: -10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='images' id="imageBack" style="background-image: url('http://data.whicdn.com/images/20948152/large.png')">

    <div class='content' id="content">
      <div id="imageLinks">
        <a href="#" data-src='http://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/660/cpsprodpb/1325A/production/_88762487_junk_food.jpg'>1</a>
        <a href="#" data-src='http://i.imgur.com/NhDejjN.jpg'>2</a>
        <a href="#" data-src='https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/80/40/9d/80409d8c06d21e0c0416a40c2176def3.jpg'>3</a>
        <a href="#" data-src='http://data.whicdn.com/images/20948152/large.png'>4</a>
      </div>
      <span id="content-resize"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't played with this much, so I am sure there are some unnoticed issues, but it offers some improvement while doing what I think you are describing. Addresses @ScottFanetti comments. Written in ES6. Hopefully it may help you to continue experimenting, or give someone else a starting point.

```js
const content = document.getElementById('content');
const startW = content.clientWidth;
const imageBack = document.getElementById('imageBack');
let resizable;
let originalW;
let originalX;

document.getElementById('content-resize').addEventListener('dragstart', (e) => e.preventDefault(), false);
document.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  resizable = e.target.id === 'content-resize';
  if (resizable) {
    originalW = content.clientWidth;
    originalX = e.clientX;
  } else if (e.target.tagName === 'A' && e.target.dataset.src) {
    imageBack.style.backgroundImage = `url(${e.target.dataset.src})`;
  }
}, false);
document.addEventListener('mouseup', () => resizable = false, false);
document.addEventListener('mouseenter', (e) => resizable = imageBack.contains(e.target), false);
document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  if (resizable) {
    content.style.width = `${Math.min(originalW - e.clientX + originalX, startW)}px`;
  }
}, false);
```

```css
html,
body {
  min-height: 100% !important;
  height: 100%;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.images {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100% !important;
  height: 100%;
}
#content {
  min-height: 100% !important;
  height: 100%;
  /*Change this to change width*/
  width: 70%;
  resize: horizontal;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  background: white;
}
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
span {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 20px);
  left: -10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="images" id="imageBack" style="background-image: url(//data.whicdn.com/images/20948152/large.png)">
    <div class="content" id="content">
      <div id="imageLinks">
        <a href="#" data-src="//ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/660/cpsprodpb/1325A/production/_88762487_junk_food.jpg">1</a>
        <a href="#" data-src="//i.imgur.com/NhDejjN.jpg">2</a>
        <a href="#" data-src="//s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/80/40/9d/80409d8c06d21e0c0416a40c2176def3.jpg">3</a>
        <a href="#" data-src="//data.whicdn.com/images/20948152/large.png">4</a>
      </div>
      <span id="content-resize"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```